# Backend Admin 404 not found for jscolor.js

Tags: magento2, upgrade, static-content

I recently did an upgrade, compile, reindex, flush, clean on my magento 2.0.7 instance. Everything is working fine except on the backend interface I am getting 404 not found on anything in the `pub/media/js/directory`. Specifically the `jscolor.js` file used in the color picker on the admin backend. I checked the permissions and confirmed the files are in fact there. So I am looking for any tips on how to resolve.

chrome debug window shows its trying to access: `https://myurl.com/index.php/pub/media/js/jscolor.js`

Thanks!

Comment: You try to run static content deploy?

Comment: why jscolor.js is located in media folder? Do you upload it with WYSIWYG editor?  Normally all js files should be placed  in pub/static folder.

Comment: @Khoa Yes, I did run static content deploy as well.

Comment: @KAndy, Should it not be there? This is a magento2 installation and I didnt manually upload anything.

Comment: did u try to give permission to the pub folder after running static content deploy ?

Comment: File jscolor.js is do not part of Magento2 and media directory is for user-uploaded content.

Answer (score 0):

Add `app\code\Vendor\Modulename\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jsfilename': 'Vendor_Modulename/js/jsfilename'
        }
    }
};
e.g.If JS file name is jscolor.js, jsfilename = jscolor
```

Add jscolor.js iin below path

```
app\code\Vendor\Modulename\view\frontend\web\js\jscolor.js
```

Run below command

```
chmod -R 777 var pub

php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If still there is a 404 not found issue, remove below file and again run above command.

```
pub\static\_requirejs\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\requirejs-config.js
```

If you are using different theme, use theme name instead of `**luma**` in above command.